# How to implement Spring batch remoting and still maintain order of writing?

Tags: java, spring, batch-processing, spring-batch

I am new to Spring Batch and have just begun to conduct a POC to prove that Spring Batch is capable of processing 1m records in a hour. The architecture however demands that we demonstrate horizontally scalablity as well.

I have read through both the Partitoning and Remote Chunking strategies. Both make sense to me. The essential difference between the two is that Remote Chunking requires a durable message queue as the actual write out to the database or file happens from the master. In partioning a durable message queue is not needed as the write happens from the slave.

Where I am totally lost however is, how to ensure that the results of these 2 variants of parallel processing are written out in the correct sequence? .

Let's take partinioning for example. As far as I understand if a particular step dealing with 1000 records is partioned into 10 parallel step executions each having it's own Reader,Processor and Writer, one of the executions could easily complete before the other. The result is that the ItemWriter of one of the step executions could write the results of processing records 300-400 to a table before results of processing 200-300 are written out to the same table, as that particular step execution could be lagging behind.

What this means is that now I have a output table which does have all results of the processing but they are not in the correct sorted order. A further round of sequential processing may be required just bring them back to the correct sorted order of 1 through to 1000.

I am struggling to understand, how I can ensure correct sorted output and at the same time scale the system horizontally through the remote processing strategies described in Spring Batch.

I have read both these books. http://www.manning.com/templier/ as well as http://www.apress.com/9781430234524 but there is nothing in those books either that answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't do that because Table are naturally unsorted. If you need them to be ordered in some way add a order column managed by writer. First partition write 1-100, second partition 101-200 and so on. Next step reader will get items order by [order column]. Holes between order column due to missing write in previous partitioners are not an issue. My 2 cents

Comment: I am veering towards something similar. I am thinking of implementing a StepExecutionListener and overriding the afterStep method. So once the item writer does it's job and the afterStep gets called I will call a database proc from the afterStep to sort the records.

Comment: If you were able to sort in afterStep why not reading ordered in next step and avoid update in listener? If sp goes wrong and you have unordered items in next step? IMO data update should be done (as much as possible) in transaction lifecycle (ie chunck life)